# Make changes to a number of buttons programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view with 10 buttons and I want to use information from an array to set how many of the buttons are visible and what their title is.

The buttons are named option1BTN...option10BTN. The array has different data and size depending on what the user selects and I want to buttons to also reflect the changes.

The code below shows a for-do loop, that sets which button is visible and the button title

```
for (int i=0; i == [optionsArray count]; i++) {

    self.option1BTN.hidden = NO;
    [self.option1BTN setTitle:[optionsArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

How can I change the button name (programatically) in the loop so that depending on the size of the array it changes to option1BTN then option2BTN...optionXBTN and so on?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a UICollectionView

Comment: You keep an array of buttons optionButtons. Then access them with optionButtons[i] in the loop. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *buttons = @[self.option1BTN, self.option2BTN]; // add all the buttons here 

for (int i=0; i < buttons.count; i++) {
    UIButton *button = buttons[i];
    button.hidden = NO;
    [button setTitle:[optionsArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // the previous line can be re-written as
    //[button setTitle:optionsArray[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The difference between this approach and using an `IBOutletCollection` (as Jeff suggests in his answer) is that the outlet collection does not guarantee the order of its items. If the order is important to you, you need to specify it yourself, like in my code snippet above.

Comment: actually looking at this again, I'm not sure it actually does what I need it to do... is this creating a new button every time? I want to use the same 10 buttons eveytime as the buttons have code they need to run. Once I set the values of "button" do I then put these back in the array? At what point do the values get displayed?

Comment: Have you tried this? This is not creating any new buttons. What happens inside the loop is you go through the buttons in order. For each button you say, okay, now I'll take button #1 and call it `button`. You set the title and the hidden property for that button. That is repeated for each of your buttons. If your buttons are on the screens, the changes will be visible immediately.

Comment: I just ran through this again and now it works! lol sorry not sure what the issue was the first time. Thank's again!

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options, one is to use an `IBOutletCollection` (if your buttons are created in Interface Builder). Each `UIButton` will be stored in the collection and you can retrieve the right button in the loop from the collection.

Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

In IB, you will need to link each button to the `IBOutletCollection`. Then in your code you will be able to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < optionsArray.count; i++) {
    UIButton *tempButton = self.buttons[i];
    tempButton.hidden = NO;
    [tempButton setTitle:[optionsArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    tempButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

The ordering of an `IBOutletCollection` is not always guaranteed so you may need to use a combination of `IBOutletCollection` and view tagging (see end of post). For more information on `IBOutletCollection's` see [NSHipster's article](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/)

Second option is if your buttons are created programmatically, store each button in an `NSMutableArray` as you create it:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *buttons;

UIButton *myButton;
// Do something...

[self.buttons addObject:option1BTN];
```

Then use the same loop as before.

A third (not recommended option), would be to tag each `UIButton` and then you can use the [`viewWithTag:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:) method to retrieve the button. E.g. using the above code again but getting the button with:

```
UIButton *tempButton = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
```